# How to add icon search path in kde4/ plasma5?

Tags: kde, icons, kde4, plasma, plasma5

I have various non-kde apps that place icons in various places in the system, and the Plasma5 menu and task manager widgets ignore them unless I symlink to them ONLY in:

- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/<icon-name>.svg` (if icon is svg) OR
- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/<icon-name>.png` (if icon is 48x48) OR
- `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/<icon-name>.png` (if icon is 32x32)
- *Oddly,* 128x128 does *not* work, and large icons must be resized either to 48x48 or 32x32 and put in the corresponding directory.

Why is this and how can I add more search paths and icon sizes? For example, `gworldclock` puts an icon only in `/usr/share/pixmaps/gworldclock.png`, and other apps only install 128x128 icons.

**Already tried:**

I tried modifying the `KDEDIRS` in `~/.kde/env/somefile.sh` and `~/.pam_environment` , and neither of those had any effect on the output of `kde4-config --path icon`. I also creating symlinks in my user icon directory (.kde/share/icons/), which also had no effect. Specifying absolute paths to icons in desktop files also seems not to work (although I only tried that with 128x128 icons so far).

**More info:**

Current search path:

```
$ kde4-config --path icon
/home/oleg/.kde/share/icons/:/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/icons/:/usr/share/icons/
```

Software versions (Kubuntu 15.04):

```
$ kde4-config --version
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.13
kde4-config: 1.0
$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.4.2
```